# Vuejs Deployment issues: IIS, routes

Tags: iis, vue.js

I am struggling with the deployment of a Vuejs front-end on my local IIS.
I would like to have my app deployed into a folder named FE_STB which is a sub-directory within my C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder.

Ideally, the URL to access the front-end would be http://localhost/FE_STB/.

In order to do so, I tried the following in vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  // Used to build the path for the css, js
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/FE_STB/'
    : '/',
  // The folder where the app will be built in the project directory instead of the default dist folder
  // outputDir: 'Vue',
};
```

running `npm run build` generates an index.html, a favicon.ico, my img, js, css and fonts folders. 
The index.html contains link tags such as (`<link href=/FE_STB/css/chunk-05c5.672f5bfa.css />`) and i thought it was going in the good direction.

However, it keeps returning a

> 404 not found error

when i try to access http://localhost/FE_STB/.

On the other hand, If I copy only the index.html into the root directory of my IIS installation (wwwroot) instead of the FE_STB subdirectory, and check the http://localhost/ URL, my app appears correctly.

However, when I start browsing the app and hit the refresh button, I get an error. For example, If I am on http://localhost/about/ on my app and refresh it with F5, I will get a 404 error as it’s looking for C:\inetpub\wwwroot\about\ directory which doesn’t exist obviously.

I also tried the web.config and the IISrewrite solutions as explained on the [vuejs website](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html) or tried to add:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  // To define sub-directory folder for the deployment
  base: 'FE_STB',
  routes,
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    return savedPosition || { x: 0, y: 0 };
  },
});
```

in my router.js but it doesn’t change anything.

Any tips or directions would be really helpful.

Thank you

S.

Comment: Hi, did you ever got this running ?